# What is the difference between Flux.sample(with Duration) and Flux.sampleTimeout()?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive

The 2 overloads of this methods:
[image]

```
public final <U> Flux<T> sampleTimeout(Function<? super T,? extends Publisher<U>> throttlerFactory)
```

and

```
public final <U> Flux<T> sampleTimeout(Function<? super T,? extends Publisher<U>> throttlerFactory,
                                       int maxConcurrency)
```

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html

Any one can help me to understand these 2 methods? I have understood sample with Duration, but I don't quite understand sampleTimeout().